# кнопка submit не передает в консоль данные

Tags: button, submit, required

меня интересует 2 вопроса, когда в текстовом поле есть атрибут required и кнопка с типом submit, то при её(кнопки) нажатии подсвечивается обязательность заполнения текстового поля, НО, когда меняю тип кнопки на button, required не срабатывает.
вопрос второй, опять же, если кнопка типа submit, ничего не происходит, когда button, то в консоле отображается значение поля. так вот, мне нужно сделать чтоб: 
1. если поле пустое, показывало, что поле обязательное для заполнения
2. значение поля отобразить в консоли
P.S.: чистый js, и ничего лишнего

```
<form>
<span>введите имя</span><input id="text" type="text" required><br>
<input type="button" value="сохранить" onclick="go()">
</form>

<script>
function go() {
var field=document.getElementById('text').value;
var obj=new Object();
obj.name=field;
console.log(obj);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<form onsubmit="go(); return false">
  <span>введите имя</span><input id="text" type="text" required><br>
  <input type="submit" value="сохранить">
</form>

<script>
  function go() {
    var field = document.getElementById('text').value;
    var obj = new Object();
    obj.name = field;
    console.log(obj);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

При использовании кнопки `submit` вы отправляете форму, но событие `onclick` она не воспринимает. Вы можете отлавливать событие `submit` с помощью jQuery. Подробнее Вы можете узнать на сайте документации по jQuery: https://api.jquery.com/submit/.